# Get short date for System Nullable datetime (datetime ?) in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, datetime, nullable

How to get short date for Get short date for `System Nullable datetime (datetime ?)`

for ed `12/31/2013 12:00:00` --> only should return `12/31/2013`.

I don't see the `ToShortDateString` available.

Comment: OP - Always remember that when using generics the underlying class's methods are available if you are able to expose the underlying class.  In this case using the `.Value` method of `System.Nullable`  Take a look at my answer for further reference.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You need to use `.Value` first (Since it's nullable).

```
var shortString = yourDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

But also check that `yourDate` has a value:

```
if (yourDate.HasValue) {
   var shortString = yourDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
}
```

Comment: And check if `yourDate.HasValue` first.

Answer (score 22):

`string.Format("{0:d}", dt);` works:

```
DateTime? dt = (DateTime?)DateTime.Now;
string dateToday = string.Format("{0:d}", dt);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/20VUv1)

If the `DateTime?` is `null` this returns an empty string.

Note that the ["d" custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dSpecifier) is identical to [`ToShortDateString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it can handle null values gracefully. Optionally you could use string interpolation - 
DateTime? dt = (DateTime?)DateTime.Now;
string dateToday = $"{dt:d}"

Answer (score 8):

That function is absolutely available within the `DateTime` class.  Please refer to the MSDN documentation for the class:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx

Since `Nullable` is a generic on top of the `DateTime` class you will need to use the `.Value` property of the `DateTime?` instance to call the underlying class methods as seen below:

```
DateTime? date;
String shortDateString;
shortDateString = date.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

Just be aware that if you attempt this while `date` is null an exception will be thrown.

Comment: `DateTime != DateTime?` (`Nullable<DateTime>`).

Comment: @Corak aware of that, but since nullable is technically a generic you can still utulize the underlying class's methods.  I should have added that you do need to use the Value property though to use the underlying class methods.  I'll edit my post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to be guaranteed to have a value to display, you can use `GetValueOrDefault()` in conjunction with the `ToShortDateString` method that other postelike this:

```
yourDate.GetValueOrDefault().ToShortDateString();
```

This will show 01/01/0001 if the value happened to be null.

Answer (score 2):

A more concise way to do the same thing would be this:

```
var shortString = yourDate?.ToShortDateString();
```

It returns a null if it is a null and the short date if it is not null.

Comment: I feel that you're on the right track here, but the code you've posted is incorrect. You really should write a small block of code that demonstrates the technique - actually run it to make sure it works - and then post that as part of your answer. You're close to having the best answer for this question but you've ham-fisted it.

Comment: @Enigmativity you are right. I have edited my answer and will try to be more careful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Check if it has value, then get required date

```
if (nullDate.HasValue)
{
     nullDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    if (nullDate.HasValue)
    {
         nullDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .cshtml then you can use as

```
<td>@(item.InvoiceDate==null?"":DateTime.Parse(item.YourDate.ToString()).ToShortDateString())</td>
```

or if you try to find short date in action or method in c# then

```
yourDate.GetValueOrDefault().ToShortDateString();
```

And is already answered above by Steve.

I have shared this as i used in my project. it works fine. Thank you.