# Null value in linq query throws null value error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm pulling results from a db however when there a null value in a column i'm getting an error 
and using convert.todatetime to format the date to display in a gridview on the page.

```
var ua = from utilacti in db.utility_activations
             where utilacti.ua_case_number == property.property_case_number 
             select new
             {
                 id = utilacti.ua_id,
                 Buyer = utilacti.ua_b,
                 BuyerPhone = utilacti.ua_b_p,
                 BuyerEmail = utilacti.ua_b_e,
                 BrokerAgent = utilacti.ua_ba_n,
                 BAPhone = utilacti.ua_b_p,
                 BAEmail = utilacti.ua_b_email,
                 Date = Convert.ToDateTime(utilacti.ua_d).ToShortDateString(),                                         
                 TonD = Convert.ToDateTime(utilacti.ua_td).ToShortDateString(),
                 ToffD = Convert.ToDateTime(utilacti.ua_tod).ToShortDateString(),
                 ApprovalD = Convert.ToDateTime(utilacti.ua_ad).ToShortDateString()
             };
```

I've tried to make the convert into the following to allow for a nullable

```
Convert.ToDateTime((DateTime?)utilacti.ua_td).ToShortDateString()
```

But it's not working.

I've tried to check for null value. I've tried to do an if in there to check for a value but it errors out.

Any ideas.

Comment: try using DBNull.Value.Equals(utilacti.ua_td) or whatever your column name is

Comment: Unexpected type code: DBNull... no go

Comment: I just see this as such an abuse of the `var` and anonymous classes... If you weren't writing a `select` for 15 different fields (some of which are derived) then you'd never encounter these problems to begin with.

Comment: Just to let you know I added a class to hold the variables. Unfortunately that wasn't the issue. It lay in attempting to convert a null value to a datetime. Which will always throw an error. a simple string.Format solved everything. And it didn't have anyting to do with abusing the var and anonymous classes.

Answer (score 3):

Check for null and then convert like:

```
Date = utilacti.ua_d == null ? "" : Convert.ToDateTime(utilacti.ua_d).ToShortDateString()
```

if `utilacti.ua_d` is of type `DateTime?` or `Nullable<DateTime>` then you can do:

```
Date = utilacti.ua_d.HasValue ? utilacti.ua_d.Value.ToShortDateString() : "" //or null
```

If you are getting back `DBNull` then you can use [`Convert.IsDbNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.isdbnull.aspx) method like:

```
Date = Convert.IsDBNull(utilacti.ua_d) ? "" : utilacti.ua_d.Value.ToShortDateString()
```

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not translate expression  for both

Comment: You got me thinking. If I do this.    


ApprovalD = (DateTime?)utilacti.ua_approval_date

it works. but when I attempt to do to shortdatestring or somethign it errors out

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Habib he got me looking in another direction.

[Get short date for System Nullable datetime (datetime ?) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982303/get-short-date-for-system-nullable-datetime-datetime-in-c-sharp)

```
ApprovalD = string.Format("{0:d}", utilacti.ua_ad)
```

It would seem that anytime you attempt to add the ToShortDateString() to a possible null value you raise an error. Null values cannot be parsed. It's not a DateTime obj. And attempting to check with the ?: operator breaks the query and throws an error.

However string.Format simply ignores the null. It just works.