# error-cannot convert from 'System.DateTime?' to 'string' C#

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

Here LogInTime and LogOutTime are datetime datatype. How to convert string format code with respect to Datetime in c#?

LogOutTime and LogInTime both are datetime datatype.

```
new
{             
    AccessDate = (DateTime.TryParse(x.LogOutTime, out parsed)) ? parsed.ToShortDateString() : "Unknown",
    AccessTimeFrame = (DateTime.TryParse(x.LogOutTime, out parsed)) ? parsed.ToShortTimeString() : "Unknown"
}
```

Now it occurred error. 
"cannot convert from 'System.DateTime?' to 'string'"

Comment: You must at least say what type are `AccessDate` and `AccessTimeFrame `

Comment: @Pikoh I guess they are `string` because he can assign `"Unknown"` to them, and I guess they are not `object`.

Comment: @meJustAndrew Judging from the error message he included, they are DateTime Variables.

Comment: @Kieran no, they are strings, for sure, and this is a duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get short date for System Nullable datetime (datetime ?) in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982303/get-short-date-for-system-nullable-datetime-datetime-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I'm sorry, but i insist. To answer this question, we should know all the types of the variables involved.

Comment: @Pikoh Actually, early LogOutTime and LogInTime were string format. Now changed its datatype into datetime. Now I want to rewrite the code

Comment: have you seen the first comment of Pikoh?

Comment: So, finally the question is: What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: @Pikoh I want this code into datetime format. If LogOutTime is null, then return "Unknown" that all.

Comment: Then edit your question and tell us what are the input parameters with their types, and what type do you expect as an output (`string` or `DateTime`). And why do you have somewhere in your code a nullable `Datetime`?

Comment: @Pikoh If database logouttime is null then I want to something like the information is  "Unknown". So

Comment: The title of this post is "error-cannot convert from 'System.DateTime?' to 'string' C#" and your Question is " How to convert string format code with respect to Datetime in c#?"  Are you wanting to convert Date to String format or a Date string to Date format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DateTime.TryParse` first argument to this method must be of String type, you are passing DateTime object only. Convert `x.LogOutTime` to String.

Go through this link, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
DateTime parsedDateTimeObj;
AccessDate = (DateTime.TryParse(x.LogOutTime.ToString(), out parsedDateTimeObj)) ? parsedDateTimeObj.ToShortDateString() : "Unknown";
```

is correct according to me.

Comment: I get an Error CS0103: The name 'parsed' does not exist in the current context (CS0103)

Comment: **parsed** simply is a variable of type **DateTime** being declared by @lashja, anyways thanks for raising concern, will update my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Change `'Unknown'` to `DateTime.MinValue`.
I assume your issue is occuring because you are trying to set the value of a datetime variable to a string.

Comment: Please note that, Error occuring is **"cannot convert from 'System.DateTime?' to 'string'"** and others before upvoting please go through question and answer posted here.

Comment: The above solution will generate new error as **Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'System.DateTime'** please stop misguiding

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `.Value` first (Because it's nullable).

```
new
{             
    AccessDate = (DateTime.TryParse(x.LogOutTime, out parsed)) ? parsed.Value.ToShortDateString() : "Unknown",
    AccessTimeFrame = (DateTime.TryParse(x.LogOutTime, out parsed)) ? parsed.Value.ToShortTimeString() : "Unknown"
}
```

Comment: This error will be generated when you try above code, **'DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'DateTime' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Comment: I thing `parsed` type is nullable according to error(cannot convert from 'System.DateTime?' to 'string')

Comment: Where is the parsed coming from? does not work in C#, .NET Core 2.0, Visual Studio 2017

Comment: @OracularMan You must declare `parsed` type of `DateTime?` variable above.Then I recommend to read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx .Thank you for downvote